# How can I know the specific type of a void * pointer pointed to?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Here's my code.

```
static void testFuc (void *p){
    id obj = (__bridge_transfer id)p;
    Class objClass = object_getClass(obj);
}
```

I got an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error everytime.Can anyone help?

Comment: Where did you get the argument from? Code? Why do you use `void*` as parameter type instead of `id`?

Comment: I want use runtime to swizzle system function free(void *p) with my own testFuc(void *p),

Comment: Functions are not methods. They are not dynamically dispatch through the runtime environment. However, this does not answer my question.

Comment: I hooked the free(void *) method of C and overwrited it.so that i get  void* as paramete type.

Comment: If you really hooked system's `free()`, then all memory freeing will go through this function. Not all passed pointers point to an object (in the sense of Objective-C). `p`can point to a C string, to a C array of `int`, to an ordinary `double`– whatever exists in C.

Comment: So let's have a broader view to your problem: What goal do you try to archive by hooking `free()`?

Comment: My app has a garbage pointer crash,and I don't know where it happened.So i thought i can hook free() and replace the mem (if it was an object) with my own class,and use forwardingTargetForSelector() to print some useful infomation.

Comment: There are tools for debugging dangling pointers. I recommend that you do some research on how you can do it with what tools. Hooking `free()` your own is no good idea. You can try to ask a new Q on SO with this subject, but I do not know, whether it is accepted.

Comment: OK，I'll do more research and find a better way.Thanks!!!

Comment: Ah, you are on Xcode … I forgot that. Try to use Instruments, likely the allocations profile. It will record lifetime of heap objects for you.